# Bootstrap 4 form validation with Vanilla JS malfunction

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I was able to create a script to validate my Bootstrap 4 form but somehow the error message is REPLACING the input field. Is there an elegant way to validate a BS4 with Vanilla JS or I should just go down the road of using Bootstrap validation? What's the best practice in the industry? It's my first time dealing with form validation.

Here's the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/wunrsjdy/

HTML:

```
          <div class="container">
            <div id="form">
              <h1 class="page-title">Quer Ser Nosso Cliente? Preencha o Questionário Abaixo</h1>



              <form id="form-user" action ="#" method="POST">
                <div class="form-group" id='errorTeste'>
                  <label for="name">Empresa</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name= "name" placeholder="">
                </div>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="button-send">Enviar</button>
                </form>


            </div>
```

JS

```
const name = document.getElementById('name')
const form = document.getElementById('form-user')
const errorElement = document.getElementById('errorTeste')

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    let messages = []
    if (name.value === '' || name.value == null) {
        messages.push('Preencha o nome')
    }

    if (messages.length > 0) {

    e.preventDefault()
    errorElement.innerText = messages.join(', ')
    }
})
```

Comment: I believe the html in your question is incomplete.

Comment: @FarizFakkel, yeah I completed with the same code I used in the fiddle now.

Answer (score 0):

In your fiddle, you are changing the `innerText` attribute of `errorElement`. But `errorElement` is also (equal to) your `.form-group` element:

```
const errorElement = document.getElementById('errorTeste')

// A little further down your html...
<div class="form-group" id='errorTeste'>
```

I believe that this causes your `input` and `label` elements in `.form-group` to be replaced by the inner text.

I feel you are on the right track, though. Try showing another element that contains a styled error/warning message when a user input is invalid using the element's `style.display` attribute. Maybe you tried giving the `#errorTeste` id to a separate error message element, but assigned it to the `.form-group` element by accident? Just a hunch.

Here's a decent example of how you could make it look:

[image]